# Adding spaces between operators and operands

Tags: atom-editor

Is there any package that lets you automatically add spaces between operators and operands in atom text editor?

I would like to go from `int i=2;` to `int i = 2;`, preferably without having to add spaces myself. I know formatting packages such as `beautify` could do the job, but those packages oftentimes do much more than just fix spaces and are relatively large in size. All I want is the spaces, not an overhaul in formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) Install `atom-beautify`

(2) Install `uncrustify`; follow this [link](https://github.com/Glavin001/atom-beautify/issues/772) if you're on windows

(3) In `atom`, go to `packages`, `beautify` settings; Set C/C++ beautifier to `uncrustify`; (I use C/C++, but for whatever else language, you can look up the corresponding beautifier and see how you can configure its operations and pretty much follow these steps.)

(4) Also, link in the path file to `uncrustify`'s configuration file (where ever that may be in your directory. It's a folder called `cfg`.

(5) Configure the files as you like. For spaces, `sp_compare` should be set to `add`.

**If** you would like to have a light-weight package and something that interferes with your code formatting as little as possible, then you can create your *own* configuration file (`nameOfFile.cfg`) in the right configuration folder and use this file for formatting. You can peruse the other config files to see which commands you want and only use them in your own config file for minimal interference.